# How can I make OneNote 2016 for Mac to not use SkyDrive or OneDrive? And use something else instead

Tags: mac, sync, onedrive, microsoft-onenote

OneNote 2016 for Mac can't be used offline -- without syncing data to MS cloud. This sucks, I want it to save data only locally.

But if this can't be changed, I want to, at least, it to sync data to some other cloud service. Ideally if it'd be my own VPS server or storage. Or just other, non-Microsoft cloud - a one of my choise.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : You cannot.

Long answer : OneNote uses a syncing algorithm called COBALT to sync sections of
documents rather than documents, in order to sync faster and support concurrent updates.
The COBALT protocol is only supported by OneDrive.

The most you can do is specify a save location that is also the sync folder
of Dropbox or another cloud service, but you are still going to get
in trouble with links to images or other embedded objects.

As you are on the Mac, there is said to be a Onenote-clone called Outline+,
which is said to sync with Dropbox and other providers, and sync whole files
rather than sections.
It may better fit your purposes, although when syncing whole files you may
have troubles with concurrent modifications by multiple users.

Comment: i'm the only user. although, I have multiple computers and might have mulitple accounts.

Comment: but, may be I can, at least, encrypt  my note on my local computer, so that they'll be sent to OneCloud encrypted? I mean, without using the built-in encryptor of OneNote

Comment: OneNote may not be then the best solution to your needs.

Comment: You can encrypt sections of a OneNote notebook by using its desktop application. See [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/password-protect-your-notes-e5ffd8fd-e811-441a-aa02-e13f0f445933), but it seems pretty heavy to use. There are free cloud providers that encrypt, example : [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/) or [MEGA](https://mega.nz/).